# Is it okay to say "the light is shining twice brightly"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Is it okay to say "Now the light is shining twice brightly"? While Google Word gives multiple results for "twice brightly" (there is even a novel with such name, it surprisingly gives only one result for "shining twice brightly", which makes me have some doubts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Twice *as* brightly."  "Shining twice brightly" implies that the light is shining twice, which doesn't really make sense.  "Twice as brightly" implies something along the lines of "The light is shining twice as brightly as a normal light."  (If you want more information on using "as" for comparisons I would suggest a Google search for "similes".)

And although not *technically* correct, most native speakers would just say "twice as bright" rather than "brightly".

Comment: *Twice as bright* is certainly correct when used adjectivally. (*The light bulb is twice as bright.*) The use of *bright* as an adverb is even *arguably* technically correct, depending on if you allow for the use of [flat adverbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_adverb). (They used to be more common in the past.) We still have officially recognized and commonly-recognized-as-grammatical road signs like *Drive slow.*